# Is there a Java API to retrieve the audio for word pronunciation?

Tags: java, dictionary, audio, spelling

Most of the dictionary sites provide a mechanism to hear the sound of the word. Are there API(s) which allow you to retrieve this sound file?
[eSpindle](http://www.espindle.org/) seems to do this, but I don't think this is free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [forvo](https://forvo.com/) which does this.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [freetts](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/) - it is a text to speech synthesizer written entirely in Java and it is free.